# Why does the following probability identity hold (probability of at least one sucess)

Tags: probability

Assume we have a coin, which has probability $p$ for showing heads. Why does it hold that
$$P(at ~least ~one ~head) = P(first ~flip ~is ~head) + P(second~flip~is~head)\cdot P(first~flip~is~tail) + P(third~flip~is~head)\cdot P(first~and~second~flip~is~tail)?$$
I know it would be simpler to write it as $1-P(no~tails)$, but I was wondering why this works? Do we need to assume independence of the single flips here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need independence because the generally true statement is that the probability of at least one heads is (a) the probability the first heads is the first flip plus (b) the probability the first heads is the second flip plus (c) the probability the first heads is the third  flip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flipping 3 times a coin the sample space is the following

$$\Omega=\{TTT;HTT;THT;TTH;HHT;HTH;THH;HHH\}$$

The probability to get "at least one H" is

$$1-\mathbb{P}(TTT)=\mathbb{P}(HTT)+\mathbb{P}(THT)+\mathbb{P}(TTH)+\mathbb{P}(HHT)+\mathbb{P}(HTH)+\mathbb{P}(THH)+\mathbb{P}(HHH)$$

EDIT: your equation holds because it is only a different partition of the sample space

$$\underbrace{\mathbb{P}(HTT)+\mathbb{P}(HTH)+\mathbb{P}(HHT)+\mathbb{P}(HHH)}_{\text{=first flip H}}+\underbrace{\mathbb{P}(THT)+\mathbb{P}(THH)}_{\text{=First T, second H}}+\underbrace{\mathbb{P}(TTH)}_{\text{FIrst and Second T, third H}}$$

---

but this is wrong

> I know it would be simpler to write it as $1−P(no tails)$

The correct one is

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{at least one H}]=1-\mathbb{P}[\text{no Heads}]$$

Comment: Oh yes you are obviously right with the second equation, silly typo by me.
But let's put $p=0.6$, then we have $P$(at least one head) = $1 - .4^3 = 0.936$. If you would use the equation is asked you get $.6 + .4 *.6 + .6 * .4^2 = 0.936$. So it seems to work.

Comment: $1-\mathbb{P}(TTT)=\mathbb{P}(H**)+\mathbb{P}(TH*)+\mathbb{P}(TTH)$, exactly as OP stated.

Comment: @DanielMathias : sorry guys...you are absolutely right....I amendend my wrong answer with the requested explanation